# How to get first three items of a destructured array in a higher order function?

Tags: javascript

I have a users array with objects. My goal is to use a higher order function to show the first three users. I realize this can be done with slicing the array and setting the sliced items to a variable. However, what gets confusing is when the array is destructured. If I try  `const items = user.slice(0, size)` then I get an error saying user.slice is not a function. And if I try `const items = users.slice(0, size)` (not using destructuring), `"[{\&quot;"` is returned three times in the console. I would like to leave destructuring in so I can learn and return the first three users. So if the array was larger in future, it would only return the first three users. Understand this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/swgj19/19mtga0z/18/) is where I started so I have been researching each step and putting in the work to understand and progress. This [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/swgj19/j0mbsrw7/102/) is where I currently am.

```js
const users = JSON.stringify([{
    firstName: 'Sarah',
    lastName: 'Jenkins',
    email: 'sarah@gmail.com'
  },
  {
    firstName: 'Matt',
    lastName: 'Wheeler',
    email: 'matt216@gmail.com'
  },
  {
    firstName: 'Amy',
    lastName: 'Preston',
    email: 'amy@inbox.com'
  }
])

// higher order function passing placeholder
function showFirstThreeUsers(f) {
  result = f();
  for (let user of result) {
    // destructure object in higher order function
    const {
      firstName,
      ...rest
    } = user;
    const size = 3
    const items = users.slice(0, size)
    console.log(items);
  }
}
//  Parse array of objects
function grabUsers() {
  return JSON.parse(users);
}
// call higher order function passing (f)
showFirstThreeUsers(grabUsers);
```

Comment: `users` is a string, so `users.slice(0, size)` returns the same three characters of that string each time: `[{"`. It's very unclear what you are intending to do in your for loop, you redeclare each variable on each iteration but never use any of them. What is your expected output?

Comment: My expected output would be the information of the first three users or at least the firstName & lastName of the first three users. I have been learning about higher order functions and destructured objects so for learning purposes I would like to leave destructuring in and return the first three users. So in future if array grew to more users only the first three would be returned.

Comment: If you only want to show three of the objects then why iterate through them all with `for of`? How about a simple for loop: `for (let i = 0; i < 3; ++i) { const { firstName,  ...rest } = result[i];`

Comment: @StephenW Start by not using `JSON.stringify` then

Comment: @Bergi True, but I am learning about all of this and wanted to see what could be done. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other answer covers the largest problems, but there is still considerable confusion in your code.

I've kept the basic structure of your snippet, but refactored it to do what you expect.

1. Declare your `input` array and `JSON.stingify()` it.
2. Pass `grabUsers()` and optional `size` to `showFirstThreeUsers()`.
3. Retrieve parsed array using passed function.
4. Create a slice of the first `size` users.
5. Iterate over this new array using a `for...of` loop, destructure one property of each element and log that property.

```js
const input = [{ firstName: 'Sarah', lastName: 'Jenkins', email: 'sarah@gmail.com' }, { firstName: 'Matt', lastName: 'Wheeler', email: 'matt216@gmail.com' }, { firstName: 'Amy', lastName: 'Preston', email: 'amy@inbox.com' }, { firstName: 'Sam', lastName: 'Jens', email: 'samj@gmail.com' }];

const users = JSON.stringify(input) //<-- 'users' is now a string

function grabUsers() {
  return JSON.parse(users);
}

function showFirstThreeUsers(fn, size = 3) { //<-- accept a size parameter and set a default of 3
  const parsedUsers = fn(); //<-- this is now an array;

  const firstNUsers = parsedUsers.slice(0, size); //<-- create a new array of the first N elements

  for (let user of firstNUsers) {
    const { firstName } = user; //<-- only destructure what you need
    console.log(firstName);
  }
}

showFirstThreeUsers(grabUsers); //<-- default size used (3)

console.log('\n');

showFirstThreeUsers(grabUsers, 4); //<-- pass a size
```

Comment: That makes perfect sense! Thank you for also showing the difference in passing a size parameter. One question though, when I console.log it shows two quotes before the strings https://imgur.com/a/JvxddX3 What is the purpose of console.log('\n'); in doing that?

Comment: `console.log('\n')` just logs a `newline` or blank line to make a space in the output. The quotes are not part of the string, but just part of your consoles' output indicating they are strings.

Answer (score 1):

Here is solved 1st fiddle:

```js
const users = {
    sarah19: { firstName: 'Sarah', lastName: 'Jenkins', email: 'sarah@gmail.com'},
  matt216: { firstName: 'Matt', lastName: 'Wheeler', email: 'matt216@gmail.com'},
  amy286: { firstName: 'Amy', lastName: 'Preston', email: 'amy@inbox.com'}
}

function showFirstThreeUsers(x) {
  for(let i=0; i<10; i++) {
        console.log(x())
  }
 }
  
 function grabUsers() {
    const {sarah19, matt216, amy286 } = users;
  return `${sarah19.firstName} ${matt216.lastName} ${amy286.email} `
 }
showFirstThreeUsers(grabUsers)
```

#### Changes :

1. Removed the last console.log as showFirstThreeUsers is not returning any thing.
2. Removed `users` from the parameter of `grabUsers()` as you are not passing it.
3. You cannot pass object in ${} so either use JSON.stringify or pass some string in it.

Now in the second fiddle:

```js
const users = JSON.stringify([{
    firstName: 'Sarah',
    lastName: 'Jenkins',
    email: 'sarah@gmail.com'
  },
  {
    firstName: 'Matt',
    lastName: 'Wheeler',
    email: 'matt216@gmail.com'
  },
  {
    firstName: 'Amy',
    lastName: 'Preston',
    email: 'amy@inbox.com'
  }
])

// higher order function passing placeholder
function showFirstThreeUsers(f) {
  result = f();
  for (let user of result) {
    // destructure object in higher order function
    const {
      firstName,
      ...rest
    } = user;
    const size = 3
    const items = result.map(r=>`${r.firstName} ${r.lastName}`).slice(0, size)
    console.log(items);
  }
}
//  Parse array of objects
function grabUsers() {
  return JSON.parse(users);
}
// call higher order function passing (f)
showFirstThreeUsers(grabUsers);
```

#### Changes :

1. Instead of calling slice on users call it on `result` because `users` is string.
2. Used a map function on result array to show it in proper format.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. The 2nd example returns an array still of all three users information, but how would it be returned in string format like "Sarah Jenkins", "Matt Wheeler"...

Comment: I have edited my answer for this use case.

Comment: Thank you for showing me how map could be used and the examples.